# differing number of rows in cbind

Tags: r, tm, rbind, cbind

I am trying to get the frequency of words used in each post, and add them as columns to the training data, the code below is running appropriately for 1 word, for the 2nd word it throws this error.

## Function to fetch frequency of a particular word in 1000 posts

```
word_frequency <- function(w){

  for(i in 2:1000){
    review_text <- paste(Train$Post[i:i], collapse=" ")
    review_source <- VectorSource(review_text)

    corpus <- Corpus(review_source)
    corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
    corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
    corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
    corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))

    dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
    dtm2 <- as.matrix(dtm)
    frequency <- colSums(dtm2)
    frequency <- frequency[names(frequency) == w]
    frequency <- as.list(frequency)

    freq<-rbind(freq, frequency)
    freq.withNA <- sapply(freq, function(x) ifelse(x == "NULL", NA, x))
  } 
  return(freq)
}

Train <- Training[1:1000,]
```

## Loping over all the words in my wordlist and cbind-ing frequency to the base data frame.

```
for (w in wordlist) {
  freq <- as.integer()
  new <- word_frequency(w)
  Train <- cbind(Train, new)
  print(paste("Completed word ", w, sep=""))
}
```

Comment: Output:
[1] "Completed word will"
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1000, 228
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Comment: There is a lot of stuff missing here. It would be useful to produce a [minimal, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/5805670), i.e. provide a small dataset with which you can replicate the error. Also, please provide the packages that you used for the functions (e.g. `VectorSource` seems to be from the `tm` package?).

Comment: Yes, Vectorsource is from tm package, In addition I installed lot of other packages like
library(rJava)
library(tm)
library(lsa)
library(googleVis)
library(NLP)
library(openNLP)
library(RWeka)
library(magrittr)
library(openNLPmodels.en)

Comment: Hmm, it seems that something went wrong when you tried pasting the dataset.. Could you delete that comment and retry?

Comment: Why not load all of the 1,000 documents into a single Corpus? That's what "corpus" means: a collection of texts. Will be far simpler and more efficient.